# Segfault when trying to access header declared member

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a Cocos2d-x 3.14 project that I'm trying to migrate to 3.15, and it works perfectly for iOS, but it doesn't for Android. 3.14 works fine on both.

When running the 3.15 migrated version, I get a segfault when accessing a member that was declared in the header using this->member. If I add local variables it works fine.

Hpp file:

```
class GameBoard : public Layer
{
public:

    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();
    virtual bool init();
    CREATE_FUNC(GameBoard);

    // background
    Sprite* background;
    void setupBackGround();

    ...
}
```

Cpp File:

```
void GameBoard::setupBackground() {

    cocos2d::Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

    if (this->background == NULL) {
         doStuff();
    }
}
```

The line 'this->background' crashes. Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Comment: I think it is not crashing on this->background.I guess it is crashing on doStuff which might accessing uninitialized background.

Comment: Is `this` pointing to some proprly instantiated instance at that point?

Comment: Or, are you calling `GameBoard::setupBackground` on an already deleted `GameBoard` object?

Comment: @user1438832 It is crashing on that line specifically. The engine allows you to initialize a non-initialized sprite pointer using the function Sprite::create("mySprite.png"); With some additional testing it crashes solely and purely on the member variables being checked for null.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Normally cocos2d-x manages the initialization of the GameBoard class. And 'this' is definitely not NULL.  But you did just give me the idea to try the same action (accessing member) in the sample project (which only uses local variable)

Comment: @nakiya It is definitely not deleted. This happens as soon as I start the app, and the Gameboard class is the 'root' UI element of the entire cocos2d-x app, this happens during the initialization process.

Comment: @ZeroStatic : Can you post the code where you are calling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in Cocos2d-x 3.15 (at least in our project) the 'applicationResized' function is being called before the initialization of the scene. Put this together with the fact that none of the pointers being used in the NULL checks in this applicationResized function were actually initialized as NULL, which was causing false if checks to pass.

In that sense @πάνταῥεῖ was correct, 'this' (the GameBoard) was not properly instantiated at that point, but was pointing to random memory.